# How read and process a large file efficiently?

Tags: multithreading, io

I would to know how I can read a large file on disk and do some work with it efficiently.

I am dealing with this question some time.

I am thinking about it, and I believe a general solution ( not platform tied ) could be using threads and a buffer.

But I am not sure to be the best method.

I have read these entries and both are right.

[What is the best way to do a search in a large file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212255/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-search-in-a-large-file)

[What's the best way to read and parse a large text file over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137040/whats-the-best-way-to-read-and-parse-a-large-text-file-over-the-network)

So, what's your advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Determine your bottleneck first.  Use a tool that displays processor load for your program.  If it is only a few percent, the common case, then using another thread can only make your program 1% faster.

Comment: It depends heavily on the ratio of time spent reading to time spent processing. Extra threads can improve performance if it's mostly processor bound -- but can slow performance if it's mostly I/O bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using a producer-consumer model, with a single producer thread reading portions of the file sequentially and putting them in a buffer for multiple producer threads to process them in parallel.